# Second monitor remains black (nothing displayed), but the power light flickering

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, power, cable, external-display

I turned on my monitor this morning like I always do, except this time the monitor did not turn on, but instead, the power light started flickering.
My primary and tertiary monitors were working fine.
I had checked the power cable for and cuts or damage.
I had checked the VGA cable.
My PC recognised that the monitor was there.

I have am not sure how to fix this.
Any suggestings?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try and swap the power cable anyway to test all possibilities.
It turns out that was the problem. The monitor now works perfectly after getting a power cable.